# Finding the optimal directed graph of affected nodes with dependencies

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

[image: graph example]

I have a set of nodes that represent values that affect each other. I want to find the logical best path of cascading calculation so that each node is calculated only a single time after all of the ancestors that affect it are calculated.

In the graph example, this would be something like:

```
[A, B, F]
[A, C, H, G, D]
[A, E]
```

Where paths like `[A, H]`, and `[A, C, G]` are skipped since they have a better route with other required dependencies that need to calculated first.

I have tried a depth-first-search, but am having trouble thinking of a good data structure to represent this algorithm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in topological sorting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: Why is `B` not included in the set `[A, C, H, G, D]`?